# How to fix "Failed to connect to Mir" error in python-selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I was about to develop some selenium tests (running with headless firefox), when the following error popped up in the `server.log` when I was about to acquire the webdriver via this command:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile = profile, log_path = logfile)
```

Here is the error:

```
1518520162032   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser /usr/bin/firefox with args ["-marionette"]
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Error: cannot open display: :1137
```

I do not recall to have changed anything. It just worked before like a hundred times. How to fix that error???

- python 2.7.12
- Firefox: Mozilla Firefox 57.0.3
- geckodriver: 0.19.1
- selenium: 3.8.0

Comment: Solution: Reboot the computer. Cause of error: Unknown. Ubuntu maybe mixed up MIR and ISS...

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all :

```
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Error: cannot open display: :1137
```

This essentially means that the `DISPLAY` property was not set properly.

### Solution

Add the following configuration in your .bashrc :

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

Gnome on Ubuntu 16.04, the correct value is **`DISPLAY=:1`** (not `DISPLAY=:0`)

The problem might be due to env_keep variable in /etc/sudoers. So a permanent solution would be to add the following line at the end of /etc/sudoers using gedit or using sudo visudo :

```
Defaults env_keep+="DISPLAY"
```

> Note : For a detailed discussion see [*Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/871092/failed-to-connect-to-mir-failed-to-connect-to-server-socket-no-such-file-or-di)

Comment: But how can that happen all of a sudden?

Comment: It would be immature to term it _all of a sudden_. Rather these _configuration settings_ should be part of your _Test Bed_ or _Test Lab_ preparation,

Comment: How did the tests work before dozen of times WITHOUT that setting?